# DB:SEED Laravel 6 doesen't works

Tags: php, laravel

This my error that i get.

```
chenasmartin@MacBook-Air-von-Chenas blog % php artisan db:seed

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'description' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `companies` (`user_id`, `cname`, `slug`, `address`, `phone`, `website`, `logo`, `cover_photo`, `slogan`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (57, Ondricka-Mraz, ondricka-mraz, 4277 Helga Mount
Amandaview, OH 09189, 231-727-1719, parisian.net, avatar/man.jpg, cover/tumblr-image-sizes-banner.png, learn-earn and grow, Nesciunt eveniet quia iste. Architecto ipsa ad provident molestias rem nisi. Blanditiis tempora nostrum sequi error excepturi velit occaecati. Quis ab et ab reprehenderit. Facere quae et odio deserunt dolores vel autem provident. Eligendi eum dolore eos sunt dolorem. Vero est odio vel quia cum et. Velit quia et sed ipsa. Vero rerum iste laboriosam deserunt expedita similique et hic. Consequuntur enim assumenda repellat et inventore numquam. Ut saepe et beatae rerum facere. Ullam quia laudantium nisi. Autem sint sed eos fugit voluptatibus alias., 2021-03-25 12:32:59, 2021-03-25 12:32:59))

  at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'description' at row 1")
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:463

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:463

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

https://github.com/chenas-sketch/Factory

This is my github and my code that i have posted.

Comment: hi @Racker80 welcome to SO, please share the code that cause that error, you seed and migration and all of the related details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `companies` table with string column called `description` string column **can not** hold a long text, change it from string to text so it can hold that amount of data.

as a result, in your create_companies_table migration:

```
 $table->text('description')->nullable(); // nullable or not it's your choice
```